# NuGet Package Manager fail in visual studio in MacOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

[image: it gives that error message when i want to access the nuget package manager in Visual Studio Mac]

i tried to install the NuGet package but because i couldn't use the package manager i couldn't do anything

Comment: Can you access the url from a browser? It is possible that your network is blocking access.

Comment: yes i can access the url from the browser

Comment: need more detail and clarity

Comment: when i go to Tools in Visual Basic Mac OS, and i click on NuGet Package Manager that errors is shown

Comment: i cannot see any package installed or updated and i cannot install any new packages